# .net linq winforms cannot convert anonymous type

Tags: .net, sql, winforms

Hi I am trying to do a join on the two tables below but for some reason I am getting an error

```
var query = (from a in pamsEntities.appraisals
             where a.emp_no == employeeId
             join b in pamsEntities.AppraisalReadinesses on a.AppraisalReadiness.Code equals b.Code
             select new { a, b }).ToList();
```

I get the error *cannot convert anonymous type* I'm quite new to LINQ so not sure why this error would occur.

sorry guys this is what i have tired i had to modify query for telrik reporting so that i had the description in the join so can display it on a report

```
public List<appraisal> GetAppraisal(int employeeId)
    {
        List<appraisal> Appraisals = new List<appraisal>();

        try
        {

           var query = (from a in pamsEntities.appraisals
                         where a.emp_no == employeeId
                         join b in pamsEntities.AppraisalReadinesses on a.AppraisalReadiness.Code equals b.Code
                          select Tuple.Create(a, b)).ToList();
           Appraisals = query;//pamsEntities.appraisals.Where(a => a.emp_no == employeeId).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetAppraisal failed.", ex);
        }


        return Appraisals;
    }
```

this is the sql query i am trying to duplicate

```
select a.*, b.*
from appraisls a , AppraisalReadiness b
where a.Readiness = b.code
and a.emp_no = emp_code;

where empcode is just a vairable
```

that is what

Answer (score 2):

Your code projects the results into a sequence of anonymous type instances `new { a, b }`, and you are trying to use that list as a list of something else. Project the results into the proper named type instead.

For example, one solution might be

```
var query = (from a in pamsEntities.appraisals
             where a.emp_no == employeeId
             join b in pamsEntities.AppraisalReadinesses 
             on a.AppraisalReadiness.Code equals b.Code
             select Tuple.Create(a, b)).ToList();
```

This will get you a list of `Tuple<T1, T2>` where `T1` is the type of `a` and `T2` is the type of `b`. You can of course create your own custom type instead:

```
class MyType
{
    // I am guessing about the type names here, based on your query
    Appraisal Appraisal; { get; set; }
    AppraisalReadiness Readiness; { get; set; }
}
```

and use it as in

```
select new MyType { Appraisal = a, Readiness = b }
```

Comment: can you not just slect all elements as in a  sql query like going a.*

Comment: @David: You can, but when you want to materialize the results you have to do so using a proper named type.

Comment: I believe that select new {AppraisalClass = a, AppraisalReadinessClass = b} would also work

Comment: is it the way im delciaring it cause it says the same as with tupals

Comment: @David: Edit the question to show exactly what you have tried.

Comment: @phoenixgr: Why would that work? The only difference is that you have changed the names of the properties.

Comment: @David: OK, so the problem is `Appraisals = query;`. `query` is a list of `Tuple<X, Y>`, `Appraisals` is a list of `Appraisal`. It should be obvious that you cannot assign one to the other. The question does not tell us what you are trying to do -- the method returns a straight list of appraisals, why do you mix the readiness stuff in?

Comment: @Jon cause its a lookup table which holds the code and the description but only code is in Appraisal sorry i should been more clear

Comment: @Jon sorry my linq knowledge is very small only starting in at it sorry if its poor quality

Comment: @David: I still have no idea what you are trying to do. If the method is supposed to return a `List<appraisal>` then the readiness stuff cannot be a part of it. You probably need to change the signature of the method, but I really have no clue. This has nothing to do with LINQ, your method says "I return a list of names" and then you try to return a list of names *and phone numbers*. You can't do that. The signature of the method and what you are trying to return must match.

Comment: @Jon and its needs to be returned as a list as is used as a list throughout program its prob just my understanding of linq

Comment: but this is stright forward if you doing sql u just do where table1.code = table2.code

Comment: @David: I 'm not sure how else to put it. You have effectively written `List<string> Foo() { return new List<int>(); }`, only with different types instead of `string` and `int`. That is not ever possible.

Comment: ill write the query here in sql 

select a.*, b.*
from appraisls a , AppraisalReadiness b
where a.Readiness = b.code

that is what

Comment: @David: Change the return type of the method to match what is actually being returned.

Comment: @Jon i  edited it agian and showed the sql query i wish to replecate can you show me how to do it in linq to the list

Comment: @David: Have you been reading what I 'm saying at all? The query is not the problem. The return type of the method is.